# Convertir de string a número

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como puedo pasar este `string "3.099.700"` a número `3.099.700`  ya que lo necesito tal cual.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ya probo con [parseInt("string", 10);] ?

Comment: no deberia tener solo un punto el resultado?

Comment: Hola. `3.099.700` no es un número válido en JavaScript, es decir, si lo necesitas tal cual simplemente imprímelo en pantalla ya que de otra forma no vas a poder hacer operaciones aritméticas con ese número. Por otro lado, si te refieres a convertir la cadena de texto al **número** `3099700`, entonces, eso, es otro tema.

Comment: Como dice @César, ademas (en los numeros) el punto se utiliza como separador de decimales.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este no es un número 3.099.700, este si 3099700

si ocupas hacer operaciones con ese número puedes convertirlo a Number y después darle el formato que gustes podrías usar una función como esta para remover los puntos y sea un número valido

```js
function replaceDots(str) {
  if (str.includes('.')) return replaceDots(str.replace('.', ''));
  return str
}

var num = replaceDots("3.099.70");
console.log(
  Number(num)
);
```